# Cannot get Raid 5 to come online. Reduced Resiliency

Tags: raid, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 machine with raid 5.   It is giving me the reduced resiliency error but not giving me any option to get to the data.  Can anyone help?   A screenshot follows:  [image]

Thanks!

Comment: "not giving me any option to get to the data." - What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Well it gave me the notice you see in the screen shot but I cannot access the drive at all.  I'd love to be able to simply back it up before I lose it but this is kind of counter to what raid is.  I figured if one drive goes bad I'd have a chance to fix it and not lose the whole thing.

Comment: You only have 3 drives in RAID 5?

Comment: RIght now, yes.  I plan on adding more later

Comment: Storage Spaces isn't a traditional/technically a RAID setup so can you provide specifics on your Storage Spaces setup?  If you currently cannot access your files you might not have had the ability to lose any disks